# Why cannot resize array by other function?

Tags: c#, arrays, reference

According to MSDN, if all arrays are reference type, then why in the given sample code, to change the size of the array must to use the keyword `ref`? Thank you!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] test1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        ResizeArray1(test1);
        Console.WriteLine("Size 1 new = " + test1.Length);  // Size 1 new = 4 ??

        int[] test2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        ResizeArray2(ref test2);
        Console.WriteLine("Size 2 new = " + test2.Length);  // Size 2 new = 8

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void ResizeArray1(int[] arr)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref arr, 8);
    }

    static void ResizeArray2(ref int[] arr)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref arr, 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: by default, all parameters are passed by value regardless whether it's a reference type of value type.

Comment: arrays are reference types. for arrays that means that if you pass the array to another function you can change the content of the array from that function. But you can't assign another array, for that you would need `ref`

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if all arrays are reference type, then why in the given sample code,
>   to change the size of the array must to use the keyword ref?

Simply, because `Array.Resize` allocates a new array. It then copies existing element values to the new array. so to make sure changes affect the argument that was first passed into `Array.Resize` we must use `ref`. This is also because, by default, all parameters are passed by value regardless whether it's a reference type of value type.